# How to free memory using glib functions for list items

Tags: c, memory-leaks, glib, singly-linked-list

I just wrote this sample program to see how to use glib functions on a singly linked list

I tried to free the memory but it shows that zero frees ..in the below context..

While using `g_free(list)` shows one free but while valgrind is used it shows invalid free..

How to free the memory and not have any errors when valgrind?

Thank you

```
  1   #include<headers.h>
  2   int main()
  3       {
  4             printf("SINGLY LINKED LIST\n");
  5
  6             GSList *list = NULL,*iterator = NULL;
  7
  8             list = g_slist_append(list,"First_Element");
  9             printf("1st--%p\n",list);
 10
 11             list = g_slist_prepend(list,"Zeroth_Element");
 12             printf("0th--%p\n",list);
 13
 14             list = g_slist_append(list,"second_element");
 15             printf("2nd--%p\n",list);
 16
 17             for(iterator = list;iterator;iterator = iterator->next)
 18                     printf("%s\n",(char*)iterator->data);
 19
 20             g_slist_free(list);
 21     return 0;
 22     }

bash-4.1$ valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ../bin/exe
==8021== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8021== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8021== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8021== Command: ../bin/exe
==8021==
SINGLY LINKED LIST
1st--0x58fff00
0th--0x58fff10
2nd--0x58fff10
Zeroth_Element
First_Element
second_element
==8021==
==8021== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8021==     in use at exit: 4,252 bytes in 8 blocks
==8021==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 0 frees, 4,252 bytes allocated
==8021==
==8021== 240 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 6
==8021==    at 0x4C26588: memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:727)
==8021==    by 0x4C26623: posix_memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:876)
==8021==    by 0x4E8D777: ??? (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x4E8DFFB: g_slice_alloc (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x4E8F612: g_slist_append (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x400666: main (ex_main.c:8)
==8021==
==8021== 252 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 6
==8021==    at 0x4C267BB: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:593)
==8021==    by 0x4E78BF7: g_malloc0 (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x4E8CFD1: ??? (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x4E8DE8D: g_slice_alloc (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x4E8F612: g_slist_append (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x400666: main (ex_main.c:8)
==8021==
==8021== 504 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 6
==8021==    at 0x4C267BB: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:593)
==8021==    by 0x4E78BF7: g_malloc0 (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x4E8CFF1: ??? (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x4E8DE8D: g_slice_alloc (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x4E8F612: g_slist_append (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x400666: main (ex_main.c:8)
==8021==
==8021== 504 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 6
==8021==    at 0x4C267BB: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:593)
==8021==    by 0x4E78BF7: g_malloc0 (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x4E8D011: ??? (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x4E8DE8D: g_slice_alloc (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x4E8F612: g_slist_append (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x400666: main (ex_main.c:8)
==8021==
==8021== 720 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5 of 6
==8021==    at 0x4C26588: memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:727)
==8021==    by 0x4C26623: posix_memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:876)
==8021==    by 0x4E8D777: ??? (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x4E8E031: g_slice_alloc (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x4E8F612: g_slist_append (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x400666: main (ex_main.c:8)
==8021==
==8021== 2,032 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 6
==8021==    at 0x4C267BB: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:593)
==8021==    by 0x4E78BF7: g_malloc0 (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x4E8DE32: g_slice_alloc (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x4E8F612: g_slist_append (in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2800.8)
==8021==    by 0x400666: main (ex_main.c:8)
==8021==
==8021== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8021==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8021==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8021==      possibly lost: 960 bytes in 4 blocks
==8021==    still reachable: 3,292 bytes in 4 blocks
==8021==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8021==
==8021== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8021== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
bash-4.1$
```

Answer (score 1):

You will never get `valgrind` to report accurately on glib memory usage unless you find and install the glib specific exclusion files which tell `valgrind` what memory `glib` is responsible for and what not to consider in use when reporting. Why? Glib allocates quite a bit of memory for its own use, as well as for memory for all the lists, etc. that make up the toolkit. This memory is outside of what can normally be accurately reported by `valgrind`. Glib isn't the only package that has problems with `valgrind`, Mac OS doesn't play nicely with it all the time.

In that end, people, usually the glib developers, will write what are called *exclusion-lists* to address the memory reporting problem with `valgrind`. There may be more than one list required and it must match your glib release or it will be worthless. So search for a *valgrind glib exclusion file* to match your version and hopefully that will have zero mean zero again.